# Possible to have scrollable div with children able to overflow: visible?

Tags: css, scroll, overflow, transform

Im working in a scrollable aside-menu for a website containg thumbnail images. I've been trying to get the images "overflow: visible" when hovering, so the image is not cut off by the container when scaled up.

The tricky part is, that I wish to maintain the possibility to scroll vertically (and thereby disabling overflow: visible). Any suggestions / hacks how to solve this? I haven't been able to find a feasible solution yet :(

Here's a pen of the code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lwaGv

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Why do u need to disable overflow:visible to be able to scroll vertically?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, let me try to clarify :)

To be able to scroll vertically in the div I need to set overflow-y: auto/scroll, or overflow: auto/scroll but then the images are cut off when they are scaled up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**W3C specification:**

The computed values of ‘overflow-x’ and ‘overflow-y’ are the same as their specified values, except that some combinations with ‘visible’ are not possible: if one is specified as ‘visible’ and the other is ‘scroll’ or ‘auto’, then ‘visible’ is set to ‘auto’. The computed value of ‘overflow’ is equal to the computed value of ‘overflow-x’ if ‘overflow-y’ is the same; otherwise it is the pair of computed values of ‘overflow-x’ and ‘overflow-y’. :(

I tried **z-index** and **important** rule too but both failed. Is this what you need?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uYOC.png

### EDIT

Maybe you can have a look at this. I made it using multiple divs and fixed the width of divs so that they don't crop the photo on mouse hover. You can adjust the height of the containers. The background of the containers can be set to transparent.

**http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pIEih**

PS: If a scrollbar is needed, the inner(scrollable) div needs to be of width so that it can accommodate the photos when their size increases (onhover). Similarly the outer div's width has to be adjusted.

**codepen.io/anon/pen/fhyAa**

Comment: In your codepen, if I swap the z-indexs it still works. Also, removing the position relative doesn't break it. So what you have there has nothing to do with relative positioning or z-index.

What's actually happening is that the width of the children is smaller than the width of the container AND the amount scaled is less than the difference in the width of the children and their container.

So if I remove the width it breaks.